# Using Moment to compare dates to filter results

Tags: arrays, object, underscore.js, momentjs

I'm trying to filter an array of objects by the date key in each object.

```
for (var e = 0; e < arrayOfObjects.length; e++){
    var objects = arrayOfObjects[e];
    var sortDate = _.filter(objects, function(n) {moment(n.date).isAfter(moment(timeCreated).subtract(110, 'days'))});
    console.log(sortDate); //console.log((moment(timeCreated).subtract(110, 'days')));
}
```

This code returns an empty array. There is a mix of dates both before and after the timeCreated - 110 days. I also console logged each part of the comparison getting:

```
   Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: "2014-07-24", _f: "YYYY-MM-DD ", _isUTC: false, _pf: Object…}_d: Thu Jul 24 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)_f: "YYYY-MM-DD "_i: "2014-07-24"_isAMomentObject: true_isUTC: false_locale: Locale_pf: Object__proto__: Moment
dateCompare.controller.js:91 

Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: Thu Feb 12 2015 20:22:41 GMT-0800 (PST), _isUTC: false, _pf: Object, _locale: Locale…}_d: Fri Nov 14 2014 20:22:41 GMT-0800 (PST)_i: Thu Feb 12 2015 20:22:41 GMT-0800 (PST)_isAMomentObject: true_isUTC: false_locale: Locale_pf: Object__proto__: Moment
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The predicate function you pass to [`_.filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) is supposed to return `true` if the value is to be included but your predicate:

```
function(n) {moment(n.date).isAfter(moment(timeCreated).subtract(110, 'days'))}
```

always returns `undefined` because it doesn't have a `return`. JavaScript functions don't have implicit return values, you have to be explicit:

```
function(n) {
    return moment(n.date).isAfter(moment(timeCreated).subtract(110, 'days'))
// -^^^^^^
}
```

Furthermore, you're trying to `_.filter` a single object, not an array. Inside the loop you have:

```
var objects = arrayOfObjects[e];
```

and then you `_.filter(objects, ...)` which won't do anything useful.

If you include a `return` statement and filter the array:

```
_.filter(arrayOfObjects, function(n) {
    return moment(n.date).isAfter(moment(timeCreated).subtract(110, 'days'))
});
```

then it should be fine.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/p7uab8uj/

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it's not working. underscore is working as the precedents in this JS file depend on it. Moment is also working via console.log. Other ideas?

Comment: I'm receiving unfiltered results. Just to go the other way, _.result is returning undefined.

Comment: Do you have a demo on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/m3hLd937/

It won't work though because jsfiddle doesn't have moment

Comment: Your demo doesn't include `timeCreated`. You can always include extra libraries from a CDN in the *External Resources* panel in the sidebar.

Comment: I added timeCreated.  What's CDN?

Comment: You were also trying to `_.filter` an object rather than an array.

Comment: true. the result I'm getting now is the full array of values for each object unfiltered by date. but what you point out provides some new ideas! do you have further suggestions?

Comment: What specifically about http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/p7uab8uj/ doesn't work? You say that it doesn't work but I still don't know what exactly you're doing.

Comment: The _.filter as it currently is in my environment is not returning a filtered list.  Either I'm getting an empty array or an unfiltered array of values (not objects). I'm not sure what you mean by CDN. I'll try and get moment up if I know what that is.  What I want to do:
1) I have a number of objects all of which have a key value pair with date as a key

2) I want to filter/sort the objects by date keeping the objects that have a date more recent than a given date.

That's all.  Although that sounds clear to me, maybe it isn't to you, so please let me know when/how to elaborate.

Comment: I gave you an example at jsfiddle.net that has moment.js and works as expected. I still don't know what your `timeCreated` is, you say you added it but I can't see it anywhere. "CDN" is "Content Delivery Network", 5s on Google would solve that. This is a bit frustrating because I don't know what you're doing and you won't show me a complete example.

Comment: Thanks for the help, sincerely. I'm trying to be clear and there's nothing more to it that I can think of at this time.  

timeCreated = 2015-02-12T23:18:35.519Z I added it to my fiddle. There's not much more to it, honestly.  When I click 'run' in your jsfiddle, nothing happens but you're right, it should work and underscore works everywhere else so I'm pretty puzzled.

Comment: I got it done with a if statement and a for loop. Thanks for the help though! Pointing out the array/object thing early got me there.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var e = 0; e < arrayOfObjects.length; e++) {
    var objects = arrayOfObjects[e];
    if (moment(objects.date).isAfter(moment(timeCreated).subtract(100, 'days'))) {
        var goodDates = [];
        goodDates.push(objects);
        console.log(goodDates);
    }
}
```